# C++ download function

Tags: c++

I've been trying to wrap my head around why this isn't working. It's downloading the file and writing it, to the correct location with the almost correct size. But the file won't open. I don't know the cause. I've embedded the code below. Please help me find the error.

The size of `outfile2.exe` is `3,188,642` bytes and the size of `fjernsupport.exe` is `3,188,312`.
Maybe it includes some headers from http ?

Here is the source code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int sock_descriptor; // integer number to access socket
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; // uses predefined sockaddr_in struct
    struct hostent *server; // from netdb.h to determine host name out of ip address
    char recvBuff[1024];  // Receiving buffer 
    char hostname[] = "localhost";

    char req[] = "GET /vikar/local/fjernsupport.exe HTTP/1.0\n"
                    "Host: localhost\n"
                    "Connection: keep-alive\n"
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache\n"
                    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\n"
                    "Pragma: no-cache\n"
                    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31\n"
                    "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\n"
                    "Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,da;q=0.4\n"
                    "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\n\n";

    sock_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // SOCK_STREAM = TCP, AF_INET = DOMAIN
    if(sock_descriptor < 0){
        std::cout << "Failed creating socket\n" << std::endl;
    }
    bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    server = gethostbyname(hostname);
    if(server==NULL){
        std::cout << "Failed to find server name" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy((char *) &(serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr), (char *)(server->h_addr), server->h_length);

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(80);  // Ensures integer interpretion is correct
    if(connect(sock_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        std::cout << "Failed to connect to server" << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << "Succesfully connected" << std::endl;
    }
    cout << "SEND: " << req << endl;
    write(sock_descriptor, req, sizeof(req));
    bool isFile = false;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("outfile2.exe", ios::out | ios::binary);
    int bytes;
    const char* phrase = "\r\n\r\n";


    while(true){
        memset(recvBuff, 0, 1024);
        if((bytes = read(sock_descriptor, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0){
                    if(isFile){
                        outFile.write(recvBuff, bytes);

                    }else{
                        char *remain = strstr(recvBuff, phrase);
                        outFile.write(remain, bytes);
                        isFile = true;
                    }
        }else{
            outFile.close();
            cout << "Returning here";
            return 0;
        }


    }
    outFile.close();
    cout << "finished";
    return 0;

}


int findWord(std::string text, std::string word){
    if(std::string::npos != text.find(word)){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you download the file via some other means (web-browser) and then compare the two files in a binary compare function?

Comment: Why don't you just compare the original file with received one? It will at least show you what sort of data corruption happened.

Comment: Did you try opening the downloaded file in a hex editor? If there are headers you will immediately see them.

Comment: "Maybe it includes some headers from http?" You're the one with the file, not us. You tell us whether it contains headers from http.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this updated code. You have to appropriately skip `\r\n\r\n` while writing to file. You are finding it, but not skipping it.

```
if(isFile){
    outFile.write(recvBuff, bytes);
}else{
    char *remain = strstr(recvBuff, phrase);
    if(remain) {
        remain += 4; //move ahead of \r\n\r\n;
        int len = bytes - (remain - recvbuf);
        outFile.write(remain, len);
        isFile = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose this case: the header has `1026` bytes : The first 1024 bytes is `HTTP/1.1 ... 12907\r\n` and the following is `\r\n<!DOCTYPE ...`. The code will fail to find `\r\n\r\n`.

Comment: @johnchen902, that is why added `if(remain) ...`.

Comment: You sir, are genius :) Compiled, and it works like a charm ;)

Comment: @rohan In the case of `HTTP/1.1 ...\r\n` `\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n...` should become `<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n...`, but your code will result in `<html>\r\n...`.

Comment: Why would doctype + html show up when i'm downloading a file ?

Comment: @user222553 Just for an example. Of course I can change `<!DOCTYPE html>` to `ÉJyòƒ;<u‰Ø‹]üÉ`, but it's unnecessary.

Comment: @johnchen902, that will not be in body if you are just getting an exe file.

Comment: Yep, that was my first guess: bad newline handling.